# Xcode Segue push to Label

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel, uistoryboardsegue

I'm having a small problem with my push segue on Xcode Im trying to push the content of one label to another one on a different view controller, this is my current setup no errors are present and but the text on the other view controller doesn't change to match the previous window.

The first example below is my detailviewcontroller which I'm sending the information from. I have created the push segue between the detail view controller and my new view controller which is CODEVIEW and given the segue the name ShowCode.

I was wondering if I was missing line of code which would automatically activate this segues information without the need of a button but instead works when loaded.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{


if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowCode"]) {


   CODEVIEW  *CodeSender = [segue destinationViewController];

    CodeSender.CODElabel.text = _Code.text;



}
}
```

Label outlet for CODEVIEW

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *CODElabel;
```

Label outlet for detail view controller

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *Code;
```

Comment: the label is not yet created, you have to store the text in a string property and assign that property to the label in viewDidLoad

Comment: Hi thank you for responding, could you show me an example of a label string, I know how to link the outlet to the label want to know how to write the string?

Comment: Just add a new string property to CODEVIEW, and assign _Code.text to that property. In viewDidLoad assign that value to CODElabel.text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current VC:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowCode"]) {
       CODEVIEW  *CodeSender = [segue destinationViewController];
       CodeSender.codeLabeltext = _Code.text;
    }
}
```

In your target/next VC:

a) inside CODEVIEW.h interface:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *codeLabeltext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *CODElabel;
```

b) in your CODEVIEW.m implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //...
    _CODElabel.text = codeLabeltext;
    //...
}
```

Comment: If this answer is full and satisfactory for your question you could acknowledge it. Also you may comment on this and ask more clarifications.

Comment: This has resolved my issue completely, thank you for your time.